# Get taller schedule

Tags: workout-routines

I want workouts for teenagers in age  14 until 19 year.Genetics influence our body ,with no genetic is difficult to see results.I have some questions I hope to answer it in all if you could.1) Workouts that will increase high. 2) What foods-nutritients needs to help the growth.3)Sleep thinking that someone is sleeping with stretching his/her body I think will see some results. How many hours sleep I have read more than 9 and I have read only 7.4) sugar and all white similar to sugar(alats? I can't remember in English the right name) should be avoided because it delay the growing?

Comment: I'm afraid there are no workouts for height. If there were, everyone would be 6 feet or more.